# List View - display names as Last Name, First Name in Lightning

Tags: lightning-experience, formula-field, list-view

In classic, the Name field for Contacts in List View always displayed Last Name, First Name.

In lightning, they seem to have switched this to first name last name.  I would like to unswitch this.  I read to create a formula field and use that field instead.  However, SF won't allow me to remove the initial `Name` field from the **Contact Search Results** list view!

> Error: Name cannot be removed. Only the \'Is Person Account\' field can precede Name.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: I was able to remove the Name field from displayed fields on Contact's List View in LEX, however my Org is Person Account Enabled. Is your Org Person Account Enabled too?

Comment: @JayantDas yes they are enabled.  I am trying to remove it from the Search layout.  Maybe thats why?

Comment: It does look like that Name cannot be removed from Search Layout.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, you are trying to remove the **Name** field from a Contact's Search layout. Below is an excerpt of what I see in the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_searchlayout_notes.htm&type=5). Though it does not specifically call out anything about Contact, but it does look like that this is applicable for Name fields across all objects as they uniquely identify a record.

> You can’t remove unique identifying fields, such as Account Name or Case Number, from the search layouts. These fields must be listed first in the order of fields in the search layout.

You can verify this by trying to remove the Account Name field on Account search layout and you will get to see a similar error as you have reported.

I also verified this on a custom object, trying to remove the Name field, and received an error (not exactly the same because it was not related to person account at all), but it does support that Name fields cannot be removed from search layouts.

> Error: abc Name cannot be removed and must be the first field in the search layout.

Comment: Thank you.  This confirms why it didn't work, but it doesn't explain how I can achieve  Last Name, First Name in list view.

Comment: As far as List View is concerned, as I mentioned earlier in my comment, you can remove the Name field from there by choosing "Select Field to Display", and I confirmed it works fine.

Comment: that option is greyed out on Recently Viewed. Am I missing something?

Comment: So the fields on recently viewed is tied back to search layouts ([refer this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_recent_records_list_lex.htm&type=5)) and because you cannot remove the name from search layouts, your only option here is to have custom list views with name field removed.